# How to get data in fragment onViewCreated for recycleView from another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bundle

I have fragment WorkoutFragment with Bundle for data transfere to fragment DeliteFragment:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DeliteFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In DeliteFragment i have an onViewCreated method where the recycler view datacall is locketed.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    //******************************** getting data from DeliteFragment
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("text from WOF to AFJ", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle textBundle) {

            Integer number_workout_train_position = textBundle.getInt("text from WOF to AFJ");
            String nameDayTrain  = new   CardSourceImplDayTrain(getActivity()).getCardData(number_workout_train_position).getTitle().toString();

        }
    });

String nameDayTrainRW = nameDayTrain;

         recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.train_delite_recycleView);
        cardSource = new CardSourceImplDelite(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),nameDayTrainRW,nameDayTrainRW);
        adapter = new itemAdapterDelite(cardSource);
   }
```

How can i take data nameDayTrain in onViewCreated? ( so it will go to recyclerView adapter)

Answer (score 0):

Use AndroidX viewmodel libraries to communicate with your activities and fragments.It's pretty straightforward ✍️

Here:
[AndroidX Jetpack ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)